Error generating access token: Error: error:1E08010C:DECODER routines::unsupported
const express = require("express");
const { GoogleAuth } = require("google-auth-library");
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
const path = require("path");
const cors = require("cors");

// Load environment variables from the .env file
dotenv.config();

const app = express();

// Use Heroku's dynamically assigned port
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000; // Default to 3000 if not set

// Enable CORS
app.use(cors());

// Variable to store the token in memory (cache)
let cachedToken = null;
let tokenExpirationTime = null;

// Function to fetch or refresh the token
async function getAccessToken() {
if (cachedToken && Date.now() \< tokenExpirationTime) {
return cachedToken; // Return cached token if it's still valid
}

try {
let googleCredentials;

    // Check if GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS_JSON is set (for Heroku)
    if (process.env.GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS_JSON) {
      // Parse the JSON string from the environment variable on Heroku
      googleCredentials = JSON.parse(process.env.GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS_JSON);
    } else {
      // If GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS_JSON is not set, use the local file path (for local development)
      const googleCredentialsPath = process.env.GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS;
    
      if (!googleCredentialsPath) {
        throw new Error("Google credentials path is not set in environment variables");
      }
    
      // Load the credentials file locally
      googleCredentials = require(googleCredentialsPath);
    }
    
    const auth = new GoogleAuth({
      credentials: googleCredentials,
      scopes: ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly"],
    });
    
    const client = await auth.getClient();
    const accessToken = await client.getAccessToken();
    
    cachedToken = accessToken.token;
    tokenExpirationTime = Date.now() + 3600 * 1000; // Cache for 1 hour
    return cachedToken;

} catch (error) {
console.error("Error generating access token:", error);
throw new Error("Failed to generate access token");
}
}

// Middleware to add required headers for BotPress Studio
app.use((req, res, next) =\> {
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "\*");
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
next();
});

// Endpoint to get the token
app.get("/get-token", async (req, res) =\> {
try {
const token = await getAccessToken();

    // Add required headers to response
    res.setHeader("x-requested-with", "XMLHttpRequest");
    res.json({ "access token": token });

} catch (error) {
console.error("Error generating access token:", error);
res.status(500).json({ error: "Failed to generate access token" });
}
});

// Serve a dynamic HTML page
app.get("/", (req, res) =\> {
res.sendFile(path.join(\__dirname, "public", "index.html"));
});

app.listen(port, () =\> {
console.log(`Server running at http://localhost:${port}`);
});

This is the server.js code I have been using. I have set the environment variable called GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS_JSON directly in heroku via command line.
I have been using this code to ensure that the access token is fetched both on my localhost as well as my heroku app.
I am getting the error in the title when i open my heroku logs. Can anyone help me with this please?
I am not a developer and was mainly using gpt 3.5-4.0 for this project for my firm.
What am I doing wrong? Is my GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS_JSON variable not defined properly? The code I used to do that was the following:
heroku config:set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS_JSON="{"type":"service_account","project_id":"sally-441618","private_key_id":"23767b7deac85fd18251063ffaeca7d97bee9230","private_key":"-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----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\\nQWP6pu4/GJfmTQrPrGxRUoE=\\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\\n","client_email":"sally-service-account@sally-441618.iam.gserviceaccount.com","client_id":"111217675359442197341","auth_uri":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth%5C%22,%5C%22token_uri%5C%22:%5C%22https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token%5C%22,%5C%22auth_provider_x509_cert_url%5C%22:%5C%22https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs%5C%22,%5C%22client_x509_cert_url%5C%22:%5C%22https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/sally-service-account@sally-441618.iam.gserviceaccount.com%5C%22,%5C%22universe_domain%5C%22:%5C%22googleapis.com%5C%22%7D%22

